# MongoDB indexes for $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The indexes help page at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes doesn't mention $elemMatch and since it says to add an index on my 2M+ object collection I thought I'd ask this:

I am doing a query like:

```
{ lc: "eng", group: "xyz", indices: { $elemMatch: { text: "as", pos: { $gt: 1 } } } }
```

If I add an index

```
{lc:1, group:1, indices.text:1, indices.pos:1}
```

will this query with the $elemMatch component be able to be fully run through the index?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Based on your query, I imagine that your documents look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "lc" : "eng",
    "group" : "xyz",
    "indices" : [
        {
            "text" : "as",
            "pos" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "text",
            "pos" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a test collection with documents of this format, created the index, and ran the query that you posted with the .explain() option.

The index is being used as expected:

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({"lc":1, "group":1, "indices.text":1, "indices.pos":1})
> db.test.find({ lc: "eng", group: "xyz", indices: { $elemMatch: { text: "as", pos: { $gt: 1 } } } }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor lc_1_group_1_indices.text_1_indices.pos_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : NumberLong(1),
    "nscannedObjects" : NumberLong(1),
    "nscanned" : NumberLong(1),
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : NumberLong(0),
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "lc" : [
            [
                "eng",
                "eng"
            ]
        ],
        "group" : [
            [
                "xyz",
                "xyz"
            ]
        ],
        "indices.text" : [
            [
                "as",
                "as"
            ]
        ],
        "indices.pos" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Marcs-MacBook-Pro.local:27017"
}
```

The documentation on the .explain() feature may be found here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain

.explain() may be used to display information about a query, including which (if any) index is used.

Comment: Thanks Marc - and yes my documents look like that. I notice from the explain though that `indexOnly` is false. Doesn't that indicate that the BSON had to be unpacked and scanned even though the fields are all in the index?

Comment: Happy to help!  IndexOnly is not possible with a multikey index.  This is because individual embedded documents each have their own entry in the index.  The entire "indices" array is not stored in a single index entry.  Therefore, even though the index is used, the actual document(s) must be read.  This is explained in the "Exact Array Matching with an Index" section of the "Multikeys" documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys

Comment: I can understand that if I queried `db.test.find({ lc: "eng", group: "xyz", "indices.text: "as", "indices.pos": { $gt: 1 } }})` without the $elemMatch it would need to scan objects, but since the elemMatch requires the same sub-object that would already be in the index entry, wouldn't it?

Comment: The index is being used for this query.  A collection scan is not being performed.  We know that the index is being used because it is given in the "cursor" field.  "Index Only" just means that the data returned is completely in the index and the documents themselves don't need to be read.  This is not possible with a multi key index as per my previous comment.  There is more information on this in the "Covered Indexes" section of the "Retrieving a Subset of Fields" documentation.  
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-CoveredIndexes

Comment: It looks like MongoDB has to filter during the `FETCH` stage to check that the fields are in the same object. I think that makes sense - the index only indicates that the document has some embedded document(s) with those matching values, not that the matching values are in the same embedded document.