# MongoDB embedded document indexing issue

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I have data in a mongodb collection in the following format:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    Product: string,
    Modules: [
        {
            StaticModuleId: Int64,
            Set: [
                {
                    k: Int64,
                    v: {
                        Value: Double,
                        AnotherId: Int64


            }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }, 
    ...
]
```

}

Here's my index named MyIndex:

```
{
    Product: 1,
    'Modules.StaticModuleId': 1,
    'Modules.Set.k': 1,
    'Modules.Set.v.Value': 1
}
```

In the collection is 5 documents, each of which has 10 modules and 100 elements in each set, for a total of 50 modules and 5000 entries in Set. I then ran this query:

```
{
    'Product': 'Test',
    $and: [
        {
            'Modules.StaticModuleId': 2010220,
            'Modules.Set': {
                $elemMatch: {
                    k: 41439,
                    'v.Value': 2186233
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'Modules.StaticModuleId': 2010226
        },
        {
            'Modules.StaticModuleId': 2010228
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the .explain():

```
{
    cursor: 'BtreeCursor MyIndex',
    isMultiKey: true,
    n: 4,
    nscannedObjects: 941,
    nscanned: 941,
    nscannedObjectsAllPlans: 941,
    nscannedAllPlans: 941,
    scanAndOrder: false,
    indexOnly: false,
    nYields: 0,
    nChunkSkips: 0,
    millis: 52  
}
```

As I continue to add additional $elemMatch clauses the performance degrades to > 200ms. Is this type of query indexable, and if so, any ideas as to how I can improve the performance?

Comment: why do you have $and expression there?  Why not just enumerate all conditions separated by ','?

Comment: I believe that there are issues when trying to indexes inside an elemmath see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207448/mongodb-indexes-for-elemmatch IMO, you may want to consider making your modules first class citizens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to drop previous index and create with multikey flag like this:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({{'Product':1, 'Modules.StaticModuleId':1, 'Modules.Set':1, 'Modules.Set.k':1, 'Modules.Set.v.Value':1}, {multikey:true})
```

in my test case, i have only 100 scaned objects and millis=0

hint: you can load data and/or index in to memory by:

```
db.runCommand({ touch: "collection", data: true, index: true })
```

i'am using next script to reproduce problem and data preparation:

```
for(var prod=0; prod<1000; prod++) {
    prodObj={Product:"product" + prod};
    modObj=[];
    for(var mod=0; mod < 10; mod++) {
        seObj=[];
        for(var se=0; se < 100; se++) {
            seObj[se] = {k: "Int64-" + se, v:{Value:"Double-" + se}, AnotherId:"Int64"};
        }
        modObj[mod]={StaticModuleId:"Int64-"+prod, Set:seObj};
    }
    prodObj.Modules=modObj;
    db.so.insert(prodObj);
}
```

may be this is a not correct for you task

Comment: I created an index with simply 'Modules.Set': 1 and it worked without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think data model is not so good. This is a relations like model. If you can change data model to simple like this:

```
{
  Product: "string",
  StaticModuleId: "string",
  Set:
  [
    {
      k: "string",
      v: 
      {
        Value: "double",
        AnotherId: "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

you will have a more good performance and less complexity